# Scripts for security permissions

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

I want to write two scripts. They can be VBS or Windows commands.

The first one is for setting a user permission for a folder – the equivalent to a right click on a folder, properties, security, edit, add, `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

The second one is for setting a permission to run as a service – the equivalent clicks are `Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Local Security Policy`, next on left side `Local Policies / User Rights Assignment`, then on right side `Log on as a service -> add Network Service` as a user that has the required privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ms dos commands:

Folder permission:

```
CACLS path_of_folder /E /T /C /G "userName":F
```

[cacls command details](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html)

Log on as a service permission:

```
ntrights -u "userName" +r SeServiceLogonRight
```

[ntrights command details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276)

Comment: I would recommend `icacls` over `cacls`, as it's also capable of handling inheritance and changing ownership.

Comment: That link doesn't work, but if it helps, I wrote an open-source alternative: [https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan)

Answer (score 0):

This is so frustrating that we don't have ntrights tool for windows server 2008 and above. I have put up a vbscript that works.

```
Username = <domain\username>
Dim oShell 
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "secedit /export /cfg config.inf", 0, true 
oShell.Run "secedit /import /cfg config.inf /db database.sdb", 0, true

FileName = "config.inf"
OrgStr = "SeServiceLogonRight ="
RepStr = "SeServiceLogonRight = " & Username & ","
Set inputFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("config.inf", 1,1,-1)
strInputFile = inputFile.ReadAll
inputFile.Close
Set inputFile = Nothing

Set outputFile =   CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("config.inf",2,1,-1)
outputFile.Write (Replace(strInputFile,OrgStr,RepStr))
outputFile.Close
Set outputFile = Nothing

oShell.Run "secedit /configure /db database.sdb /cfg config.inf",0,true
set oShell= Nothing

Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile("config.inf") 
obj.DeleteFile("database.sdb")
```